# Синхронизация 2-х потоков

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть 2 потока, которые рисуют 2 машинки на консоли и имитируют их движение.

Машинка -Враг- спускается сверху, а игрок должен ее обойти. Отрисовка объектов сделана через `lock`.

Проблема в том , что когда мне надо "замедлить" машинку игрока, то его перемещение влево вправо так же замедлятся (по задумке не должно). Скорость реализована в виде регулировки времени `Thread.Sleep(int delta)`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста , возможные варианты решения этой проблемы.

Comment: Я так понимаю, поток ,который отвечает за передвижение объекта игрока работает всегда, что не нужно, возможно стоит сделать через событие и лочить только в том случае, если выпадет событие?

Comment: есть хорошая книга про то как писать игры http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/contents.html

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman пока что все делается исключительно ради практики,   думаю ссылка будет полезна , но позже

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman более точечно можете подсказать, какой из паттернов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне не кажется хорошей сама идея запускать логику разных объектов в разных потоках, и надеяться на планировщик для ускорения и замедления. В конце-концов, передача управления другому потоку ничем не гарантирована. (Ну и это решение очевидно не скалируется на случай, когда объектов становится много, но это уже техническая подробность.)

Я бы сделал по-другому: ввёл бы класс-координатор, который бы в цикле по очереди просил объекты сделать свой «ход», и заботился о нужной задержке (например, опрашивая скорость объектов). При таком дизайне всё бежит в одном потоке, и координатор играет роль планировщика.

Comment: 1.а возможно ли добиться такого эффекта (при замедлении скорости не терять в "маневренности" игрока) с несколькими потоками? (эффект я нужный достигнуть могу , но возникает проблема с прорисовкой , начинает неправильно отрисовывать и затираться фигуры).
2. если воспользоваться Вашим советом, то мне не совсем понятно чем отличается -сделать свой «ход»- от того же способа с локом и почему задержка в однопоточном режиме не будет тормозить  2 объект? 
Если несложно опишите , пожалуйста, подробнее схему

Comment: @MikhailZnak: (1) Наверное можно, но это не совсем правильный путь, так что проблемы всё равно будут вылазить время от времени. (Ну и я не знаю, как вы прорисовываете фигуры.)

Comment: @MikhailZnak: (2) Отличие в том, что вы в вашем способе для в качестве таймера игрового времени используете реальный таймер, и надеетесь, что "ходы" (то есть, итерации вашего цикла в каждом из потоков) будут выполняться как бы параллельно. Для случая, когда отсчёт ходов вы ведёте вручную в одном потоке, у вас гарантирована очерёдность обновлений состояния и не нужна синхронизация. И ещё не нужно делать отрисовку в другом потоке, потому что поток один.